# SKShapeNode with SKAction touch end when moves away from touch location

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently making a very simple game to test out the Swift language from Apple, so far so good but I'm stuck with a `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` events while the `SKShapeNode` is animating away from the touch location.

**The flow is this**

- Circles are animating around randomly
- I touch one of them and it sets it to active
- if the circle moves away from that touch it should become inactive
- touchesEnded should fire as usual but also when the node moves away/out of the touch location

And I can't think of a way to do this, any help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to include the code instead of just describing it.

An SKNode (or it's subclasses) do not lose a touch delegated to them even when it moves out of their apparent range. You will actually have to calculate the distance of the touch from the node's centre yourself in the `-touchesMoved` method and cancel the touch if it passes beyond a range you specify.